# MS Access with linked tables to SQLServer using FIND button

Tags: ms-access, sql-server-2008-r2, ms-access-2007

I'm using MS Access 2007 as a front end and have all linked tables in SQLServer 2008 R2 backend.

In a form in Access I am trying to execute the FIND button either in the ribbon or by creating a button on the form with the expressed purpose of looking for records with a specific value in a particular field.

When I complete the entry in the FIND window, I click on *Find Next*. In some cases, the record(s) is found immediately. In others, it can go for hours only to report that it can't find anything (when I know it should).

The table I am looking in has approximately 99,000 records in it. It doesn't seem to matter whether or not the field is indexed.

Is there something I'm doing wrong, or is Access unable to handle this?  Also, is creating a stored procedure with handling multiple search requests and passing the info to Access the answer?

Answer (score 1):

The find methods are known to be slow with ODBC data sources.  Here is what the Access 2007 `Recordset.FindFirst` Method help topic says:

*When working with Microsoft Access database engine-connected ODBC databases and large dynaset-type Recordset objects, you might discover that using the Find methods or using the Sort or Filter property is slow. To improve performance, use SQL queries with customized ORDER BY or WHERE clauses, parameter queries, or QueryDef objects that retrieve specific indexed records.*

Futhermore, binding an Access form to a record source of 99K records is a performance challenge.  Use a query as the form's record source, and design the query to return only one or a few rows.

Give the user an option to choose a different set of rows, and modify the form's record source property to reflect the user's choice.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the type of search you need and on the data type of the column (field) to be searched. For example, if I have a text data type in an indexed column and I search using Start of field or Whole field, it will be quite fast, however, if I search for Any part of field, it may well fall over. In other words, if Access can use an index for the search, it will work, even on quite a large table, otherwise, you may be best with a stored procedure, though I doubt that will be fast without an index, either.